# Google App Engine - SQL Access Control - Could not complete the operation

Tags: mysql, sql-server, google-app-engine

I've created my app and SQL container on Google App Engine. All is ready to go, I just need to grant network access to the SQL server from the application. When clicking the Add Item button, then entering the Application ID (I verified through what appears to be an ancient deprecated interface) then clicking save I get the following error:

Could not complete the operation. Dismiss

I've read the instructions and as far as I can tell this is the correct method. It's the same region as the App. Tried us-east and us-west.

I created another SQL instance just in case with the same results.

I checked the dns records of the provided application URL and added the 4 IPv4 and IPv6 addresses that were returned just in case I could do it that way. The app still can't connect to the database.

I'm not sure what to try next, does anybody have an idea how to allow access in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I created my Project in US-east1 originally, had the same problem as above. Went back and created another project in US-central. This problem "Could not complete the operation. Dismiss" went away. Easy way to tell that it is working, the "Preferred location" will auto populate with "Follow App Engine app", the "App Engine application id" will auto populate with your project app id, the "Authorized App Engine applications" will auto populate with the project app id as well.